# Use <span> inside Form Label in Blade template

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

In `html` I can use `<span>` tag inside form label like this:

```
<label for="name" class="class-name">Name:<span class="required"></span></label>
```

Using Laravel Blade, the code for label is like this:

```
{!! Form::label('name','Name:',['class'=>'class-name']) !!}
```

How can I use `<span>` inside form label using blade template?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one code:

```
{!! Html::decode(Form::label('name','Name: <span class="required"></span>')) !!}
```

Comment: First you encode, then you decode, not the best solution :)

Answer (score 8):

Just set the 4th parameter of Form::label to false which is `escape_html` = false.

```
{!! Form::label('name','Name: <span class="required"></span>', [], false) !!}
```